# How get InvalidArgumentException with Guzzle?

Tags: json, laravel, rest, guzzle

I'm sending a post through Guzzle and some products are returning the InvalidArgumentException error, how do I get this data? Unfortunately in the documentation there is nothing about this.

This is the error

```
InvalidArgumentException in functions.php line 324:
json_encode error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

My catch:

```
catch (ClientException $e) {

              if ($e->hasResponse()) {
                  $resposta = Psr7\str($e->getResponse());
                  $incrementer->cron_value = $incrementer->cron_value + 1;
                  $incrementer->save();
                  return view('home');
              }
          }
          catch (RequestException $e) {
              return view('home');
              if ($e->hasResponse()) {
                  $incrementer->cron_value = $incrementer->cron_value + 1;
                  $incrementer->save();
                  return view('home');
              }
          }
```

Comment: Always send your request in a try ..catch block e.g `try { // Your guzzle action} catch (Exception $e) {echo $e->getMessage(); }`

Comment: Yes, I used try catch, but I did not see any method to get this kind of error in the Guzzle documentation. For example, I used the ClientException and RequestException, but since the error is an InvalidArgumentException, it does not pass through try catch filtering

Comment: All exceptions can be caught if you do it right. Show us your `try`/`catch` for it.

Comment: Okay, I edited. @ceejayoz

Comment: Just add another `catch`...such as `catch(InvalidArgumentException $e)`. You can have multiple `catch()` blocks for 1 `try`. Alternatively you can capture any exception by just doing `(catch \Exception $e)` and then passing the `$e` off to another class that can `switch` on the type of exception, just like Larvael (well, Symfony in this case) does.

Comment: It works, thanks @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in Guzzle's code, there is a general exception (from the root namespace) on this line.

```
if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
        'json_encode error: ' . json_last_error_msg());
}
```

So you have to catch it in addition to other exceptions.

```
try {
    //...
} catch (ClientException $e) {
    // ...
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    // ...
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    // Your UTF error.
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!